# Node Crypto cannot decrypt files greater than highwatermark in stream

Tags: encryption, cryptography, node-streams

Iam using Node crypto but it can't seem to decrypt files greater than 63Kb which is the default stream buffer size. I increased the highWaterMark in streams and that seems to solve the problem but i thought streams takes the data in chunks so what's wrong with my code here. Streams takes the data in chunks and then i used Transform to encrypt the chunked data.

```js
const app = {
  encrypt(data) {
    const salt = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    const key = crypto.scryptSync('password', salt, 32, { N: 16384 });
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, salt)
    const encryptedData = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(data), cipher.final()]);
    const authTag = cipher.getAuthTag();

    return Buffer.concat([salt, authTag, encryptedData]);
  },
  decrypt(data) {
    const salt = data.subarray(0, 16);
    const authTag = data.subarray(16, 32);
    const encData = data.subarray(32, data.length);
    const key = crypto.scryptSync('password', salt, 32, { N: 16384 });
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, salt);
    decipher.setAuthTag(authTag);

    try {
      const plainText = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(encData), decipher.final()]);
      return plainText;
    } catch (e) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

```js
const stream = {
  encryptStream() {
    return new Transform({
      transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        const encryptedData = app.encrypt(chunk);
        callback(null, encryptedData);
      }
    })
  },
  decryptStream() {
    return new Transform({
      transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        const DecryptedData = app.decrypt(chunk);
        if (DecryptedData === true) {
          console.log('Wrong Password');
        } else {
          callback(null, DecryptedData);
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

```js
const file = {
  encrypt() {
    const fileReadStream = fs.createReadStream(fileLoc);
    fileReadStream.on('error', (err) => {
      console.log('File not found.');
    });

    const newFileLoc = './sample_enc.txt';
    const fileWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(newFileLoc);
    fileReadStream.pipe(stream.encryptStream()).pipe(fileWriteStream);
  },
  decrypt() {
    const fileReadStream = fs.createReadStream(fileLoc);
    const newFileLoc = './sample_dec.txt';

    fileReadStream.on('error', (err) => {
      console.log('File not found');
      fs.unlinkSync(newFileLoc);
    })

    const fileWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(newFileLoc);
    fileReadStream.pipe(stream.decryptStream()).pipe(fileWriteStream);
  }
}

// const fileLoc = './sample.txt';
// file.encrypt();

// const fileLoc = './sample_enc.txt';
// file.decrypt();
```

Comment: I'd bet the ReadStream's on original and encrypted use the same chunk size, but your encrypted chunks are 32 bytes bigger and MUST be read so. FYI repeating the PBKDF for each chunk will be horrible; usual practice is to derive one _key_ and use a unique _nonce_ (aka IV) for each chunk; for GCM you can just use sequential nonces so you don't need to store them (but you still must store, and read back, the tags). Also GCM is optimized for 12-byte nonce; any other size is less efficient AND less secure. But those are offtopic for SO.

Comment: PS I'm bemused that `file` gets `fileLoc` from its caller but hardcodes `newFileLoc`. I can see use-cases for putting both in the caller, or both in the callee, but doing one of each seems almost unusable.